Raceway wiring in a bathroom next to sink
I am rehabbing my bathroom in a 1923 bungalow in Chicago. I have one outlet on GFCI above the sink and it's to the left of it. I want to run a raceway wire to my wall and up and install a ventilation fan above the window. Is there anything against this in code? I know you can't have it by the shower or tub and it won't be. Here's a picture of what I am imaging.
https://imgur.com/a/eVs71Jf

Not a fan of wall-mounted fans like that one in climates as cold as yours. See if the joists run toward the window and if so consider a ceiling mounted fan with a few feet of duct. and an exhaust vent.  You'll get a flapper in the fan and another at the end of the vent to reduce cold air entering when not inuse.

Sorry I didn't say it. The joists are 2x4 so there's not much room between the ceiling and floor above. I would use a proper wall mounted ventilation fan. I just was using an image off of google image search.

That's perfectly fine. In Chicago you generally need to use wires in conduit, but there are raceways that are legitimate conduit, so you should be fine.
However, you are still in "finish the drywall mode", so unless some of the drywall doesn't have space to feed conduit, you may want to consider conduit inside the wall instead. You'll have to patch a bit more before you paint, but that shouldn't be a big deal.

But if using raceway, won't the issue be the wire penetrating the wall?  Like, how will the wire get from the junction box behind the outlet/switch cover plate to the surface?  Also, wouldn't AC/MC cable be an option (not familiar with Chicaco requirements) in lieu of conduit, if opening the wall anyway?

MC cable is allowed for rehab as far as I understand. If I were to go to bare studs, then metal conduit is required by code I believe.

@manasshkatz, that's my other option. I'm just afraid I will find out some new problem and delay this project even more haha. It started with the ceiling peeling because we never opened the window (lesson learned). And also cheap paint that the previous owner used. I have another bathroom with semigloss and it held up well. But now I am thinking about a fan.

@Huesmann Legrand wiremold has box extensions you can use to be able to transition to wiremold raceway.
